# What is the correct way to access nested objects in JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

If I understand correctly, **list** in this code is an **array** that consists of **objects**. I want to access temp in the main object and thought main.temp would do the trick, but I get an error message stating it’s undefined. Alternatively I’ve tried `list[1].main.temp`. What is the correct way to access nested arrays like this?

[image]

Comment: The first object index is 0, not 1.

Comment: I thought "dt:148..." was technically at index[0]

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by that comment.

Comment: dt, main and so on are the keys of an object inside array. "dt:148..." is not an element of an array.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct way to access nested arrays like this?

First of all these aren't nested arrays, but array of objects instead and in an `array` we access the items by index, and in `objects` we access them(entries) by keys.

So in your case `list[0]` is an `object` where `list[0].dt` is an entry and `list[0].main` is another entry of the `object`, so `dt` isn't at index `0` like you mentioned in your comment.

And to access all your array `main.temp` properties you need to loop throught the `array` elements using one of the `Array` built-in methods or just a `for loop`, because using static indexes in `list[1].main.temp` will just get the `temp` property of the firts element in the array and may throw an exception if this index is higner than the `array.length`.

This is how should be your code:

```
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    console.log(list[i].main.temp);
}
```